# Tkinter, drop down variable included in function

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an app that that calculates credit card processing fee depending on the currency someone chooses. The currency is selected from a drop down menu, and then the total is showed when the submit button is pressed. However,  I cannot get the variable to be read in my function for the button, so which ever option is chosen from the drop down menu gives the same result.
Can someone tell me where in my code I am messing up?

I tried using variable as numbers as well as text but no luck.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

OptionList = [
    "USD",
    "CAD"
]


def clicked():
    n5 = float(n1.get())
    if currency == 1:
        #consultation_total = (n5+0.3)/(1-0.055)
        #consultation_total = (((n5 * 0.14795) + n5) + 0.3) / (1 - 0.038)
        consultation_total = 5
    else:
        #consultation_total = (((n5*0.14795)+n5)+0.3)/(1-0.038)
        #consultation_total = (n5 + 0.3) / (1 - 0.055)
        consultation_total = 10
    print(round(consultation_total, 2))
    label_3 = tk.Label(consultation, text=round(consultation_total, 2))
    label_3.pack()


def clicked2():
    n1.set(0)


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('350x200')

tab_parent = ttk.Notebook(window)

consultation = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
retainer = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
conversion = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)
allocation = ttk.Frame(tab_parent)

tab_parent.add(consultation, text="Consultation")
tab_parent.add(retainer, text="Retainer")
tab_parent.add(conversion, text="Conversion")
tab_parent.add(allocation, text="Allocation")

tab_parent.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

label_1 = ttk.Label(consultation, text="Please enter the price of the consultation")
label_1.pack()

n1 = tk.DoubleVar()
consultation_input = ttk.Entry(consultation, textvariable=n1)
consultation_input.pack()

variable = StringVar(window)
variable.set(OptionList[0])

label_2 = ttk.Label(consultation, text="Select the currency")
label_2.pack()

c = tk.OptionMenu(consultation, variable, *OptionList)
c.pack()

if variable == "USD":
    currency = 1
else:
    currency = 2

labelTest = tk.Label(text="")
labelTest.pack()


def callback(*args):
    labelTest.configure(text="The selected currency is {}".format(variable.get()))


variable.trace("w", callback)


button_1 = ttk.Button(consultation, text="Submit", command=clicked)
button_1.pack()


button_2 = ttk.Button(consultation, text="Reset", command=clicked2)
button_2.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: suggestion: use a dictionary to store currency and the fee together, that way You can avoid countless nested `if/elif` statements and just access the value by currency as key

Comment: also You should fix that when submit is pressed a new label is created, instead just use `.config(text='new text')` on the existing label

Comment: the issue is that You evaluate currency at the beginning so it will stay that way, You should configure the currency value in the function or just use `if variable.get() == 'USD':`